# Pointer arrays and output

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand why the output of this code would be 7 11 and I am lost. What is `ptr[1][2]` and `ptr[2][1]` referring to?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 25
int main()
{
    int a[SIZE];
    int *ptr[5];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        a[i] = i;
    } //has values 0-24
        
    ptr[0]=a; //ptr[0] is assigned with address of array a.
    
    for (int i=1; i < 5; i++){
        ptr[i] = ptr[i-1]+5; //pp[1] = 5; pp[2] = 6??
    }
    printf("\n%d %d",ptr[1][2],ptr[2][1] ); //output is 7 11
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ptr[0]=a` assigns `&a[0]`, not `a` per-se.

Comment: `ptr[0] = &a[0]`. `ptr[1] = ptr[0] + 5 = &a[5]`. `ptr[2] = ptr[1] + 5 = &a[10]` and so on. That's what the second loop is doing.

Comment: @user3386109 How does ptr[2] = &a[10]?

Comment: You need to recognize `int *ptr[5]` as an *Array of Pointers to* `int[5]` (in other words an array of 5 pointers to `int`). You need to contrast with with `int (*ptr)[5]` which is a *Pointer to Array of* `int[5]` (in other words, a single-pointer to an array of `int` with 5-elements). With that distinction, you can look at your loop limits and for each iteration ask "What is being assigned to each pointer?"

Comment: @mathisfun1234 It may help to add some `printf` to the code. In the first loop, add `printf("&a[%d] = %p\n", i, (void *)&a[i]);` and in the second loop `printf("ptr[%d] = %p\n", i, (void *)ptr[i]);` after the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr[1] = ptr[0]+5` which refer to `a[0+5]` = `a[5]`

`ptr[2] = ptr[1]+5` which refer to `a[5+5]` = `a[10]`

so

`prt[1][2]` should be `a[5+2]` which is `a[7]` = 7

`prt[2][1]` should be `a[10+1]` which is `a[11]` = 11

Answer (score 1):

While this is quasi-valid pointer code, it's also not the sort of code you should write in practice because it's going to be quite confusing to keep track of what's going on.

Things like `ptr[i-1]+5` is kind of a mess to deal with.

What this does is effectively pluck out values 0, 5, 10, etc. through to 20 and put them into a look-up index of sorts composed of pointers.

Now that you have pointers to a contiguous array you can do sneaky things like `ptr[n][i]` where that will offset the target by `i`, but normally you'd just do `*ptr[n]` to avoid all the extra confusion.

It's worth noting that for simple index lookups it's almost always easier to store offsets than pointers. For example if you had this instead:

```c
int ptr[5];
ptr[0] = 0;

for (int i=1; i < 5; i++) {
  ptr[i] = ptr[i-1]+5;
}
```

Then later:

```c
printf("\n%d %d",a[ptr[1]],a[ptr[2]]); //output is 7 11
```

A lot easier to debug, too!